# java.lang.SecurityException with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Before you go duplicating this question, I'll explain to you what I know, what I've read other questions, and why this is not working for me.

My goal with this is to implement reflection a java based game that I have the .jar for. I attach it as an external library in my eclipse project.

I am getting the error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "Client"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

on the line

```
Class clazz = Client.class;
```

Now as mentioned in other questions. The reason for this error is that I have two referenced libraries that were signed differently? (Perhaps meaning they are compiled with different versions of java?).

The only two libraries I reference are the JRE system (my project is build on 1.7) and the .jar of the game.

Would this error be occurring maybe if the .jar was compiled on 1.6? Should I remake my project as using the JRE 1.6? How can I tell what JRE version the client was compiled with?

Thanks!

Edit: Another thought I had is perhaps the .jar file of the game itself has classes that have different signatures (perhaps to stop reflection). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would assume is following.

You have in the (signed) game jar following

```
the/game/Client.class
```

and in your (probably unsigned) reflection code you have

```
the/game/ReflectionStuff.class
```

This would cause the exception above.

**edit**

Find below a small PoC to demonstrate the problem. The first class called from a specific package defines the signed key which must be the same for all classes in the same package.

```
public class Client {
}

public class ReflectionStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = Client.class;
   }
}
```

compile the codes

```
javac -d bin/ Client.java ReflectionStuff.java
```

create the jar files

```
mkdir bin
jar cf Game.jar -C bin/ Client.class
jar cf Reflection.jar -C bin/ ReflectionStuff.class
```

generate a key for the signing

```
keytool -genkey -alias signGame -keystore gamestore.jks -storepass passStore -keypass passGame -dname "CN=John Doe"
```

sign only the game jar

```
jarsigner -keystore gamestore.jks -storepass passStore -keypass passGame -signedjar SignedGame.jar Game.jar signGame
```

call the unsigned class from the same package (the default package)

```
java -cp SignedGame.jar;Reflection.jar ReflectionStuff
```

To solve the problem move the classes into different Java packages.

Comment: Since my code and the .jar are not from the same sources is there any way to determine the signature of the jar / Client.class and mimic it / duplicate it?

Comment: @k9b If you don't own the signing key, there is no way to copy it. This would counteract the signing of a Jar file.

Comment: If you were allowed to do this, you could access and extend package private classes of a signed jar, which doesn't sound like a safe thing to do. (From the signer's perspective, that is.)

Comment: @k9b One technical possible way (which most probably would violate the license of the game) remove the signing information from the game Jar (in META-INF/manifest.mf and META-INF/*.SF)